# Delimiter between two records of a warc.gz file of common crawl

Tags: common-crawl

I want to parse warc.gz file downloaded from common crawl. I have a requirement where I have to parse the news warc.gz file manually. What is the delimiter between two records?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can parse the gzipped file manually. Your best option is to use [the index](http://index.commoncrawl.org/) to find out the offset and length of each record. See the [api documentation](https://github.com/ikreymer/pywb/wiki/CDX-Server-API#api-reference) and [the guides](http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/) for more info.

If you do what to parse the WARC files manually, unzip the .gz file first.

[WARC records are separated by two newlines](http://archive-access.sourceforge.net/warc/warc_file_format-0.9.html#anchor3):

> A WARC format file is the simple concatenation of one or more WARC
>   records. A record consists of a record header followed by a record
>   content block and two newlines. (Newlines are CRLF as per other
>   Internet standards.)

Comment: even if I unzip the .gz file, I have no way of getting each records separately. Is there a way?

Comment: As I just noted, *each record is separated by two newlines*. If you need more help, then I need more info about what you're trying to do. And why do you have to do it manually?

Comment: thanks. I have to create an rdd of that file. The default delimiter in spark is something which is not that warc has. Hence I am getting way more number of records than the file has.

Comment: i tried this file2 = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
  'hdfs://master:54310/CC-NEWS-20170803215756-00005.warc',
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
  'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
  'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
  conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': '\n\n'}
)   this still gives me more number of records than expected.

Comment: Ah. Spark. Unfortunately I can't help with that. I suggest you ask another question with **all** the details of exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what problem you're having. Then someone familiar with Spark may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unambiguous record separator in a WARC file. A record always ends with '\r\n\r\n' but this is also used to separate a record header from a record body and may occur anywhere in the HTML documents. The length of a WARC record is defined by the `Content-Length` in the record header.

To process Common Crawl WARC files with PySpark, see [cc-pyspark](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark).